# "which had return'd to the inheritance of Fortinbras"

Tags: grammar, shakespeare

Here are some lines from *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 1
(The Arden Shakespeare edited by Harold Jenkins)

> Against the which a moiety competent
>
> Was gaged by our King, which had return'd
>
> To the inheritance of Fortinbras,
>
> Had he been vanquisher;

I think "which had return'd" should be "which would have returned" in Modern English. Was "which had returned" regular at Shakespeare's time?
Or was it irregular even at that time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ordinary Elizabethan syntax - the same irrealis use of the preterite you find in the condition clause in the next line. Compare, from IV.i:

> *King.* O heauy deede!
>     It **had** beene so with vs **had** wee been there,
>     His libertie is full of threates to all,
>     To you your selfe, to vs, to euery one